# Cubes and dimension in Dataware house have 2 databases

Tags: sharepoint, ssas

I have two relational databases (Oracle & DB2), each of them in standalone server and have similar(for example : customerName in oracle & custName in DB2 is "John") data but the different in schema,I have readonly permission "Just select statements".What i need is to create dataware house from the two databases and use cubes and dimension with connected model  .How i can do that in my enviroment?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Think about your question and how nobody will be able to answer you in any way. You're asking about how to create a data warehouse "in your environment" and you tagged your question with SHarePoint and SSAS? I think we will need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the best features of Performance Point Services in SharePoint 2010, you will need a SQL Server Analysis Services cube. This requires you to import the two databases into an SQL Server database (now kown as your "datawarehouse"), transform the data into an appropriate [star schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema) and then use [Business Intelligence Development Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173767%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to create the appropriate cubes for your data.